# Generate tables from entities in IntelliJ 11 IDEA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, intellij-idea

Are there no option to generate tables from entities in IntelliJ? Using JPA and eclipselink as implementation. Trying to generate tables for MySQL. All I see is options for importing.

Do I have to use Eclipse to generate tables?

Comment: @zpontikas That question is actually the reverse of this question (db model -> entities) vs (entities -> db model).

Comment: You are right. It's the opposite question. To create tables from POJOs. It's not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not possible in IntelliJ. As far as I remember from a project 1.5 years ago, we didn't use any exporting to database, everything was done automatically upon deploy to JBoss.

Hope this helps.